# boot mode legacy or uefi hybrid or uefi native for windows 8.1

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1, bios

I am going to re-install my OS. This time i am going to install windows 8.1  instead of  windows 7.

Now I came into something new (to me ) There are different boot mode in my laptop boot option

1. Legacy
2. UEFI hybrid
3. UEFI native

I did a little study on `UEFI` still confused.

Can any one tell me which mode use for better performance and stability? with a little why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't using the retail DVD just use [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to create the USB installer with UEFI support, boot your system in Native UEFI mode and install as usual.

[image: 1]

Having read about buggy Hybrid UEFI implementations (such as [Gigabyte's](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gb-hybrid-efi/) for example), I would not recommend it.

Note that since Windows in UEFI mode can only boot from a [GPT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) partitioned drive, if your system drive is pre-partitioned as [MBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) then you'll face problems. For best results I would recommend an empty drive (you can delete existing partitions using Windows Setup itself) so that Windows can use GPT and create the necessary [WinRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment#Windows_Recovery_Environment), [ESP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) and [MSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Reserved_Partition) partitions as I've mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/a/915724/138343).

Answer (score 0):

UEFI is for security, rather than stability. To update to Windows 10, you might be required to use UEFI boot mode according to [BetaNews](http://betanews.com/2015/03/18/a-close-look-at-the-windows-10-system-requirements-for-smartphones-tablets-and-pcs/) and [Paul Thurrott](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/2257/windows-10-minimum-hardware-requirements-for-pc) (pre-release versions may support legacy mode BIOS). So for current security and future upgradability, enable UEFI.

That said, it may be necessary to use legacy mode to install the OS using whatever media you have. If so, try to enable UEFI afterwards. Check your PC manufacturer's site for information on accessing BIOS and enabling UEFI or legacy modes.

Comment: As Paul was informed by a commenter, those requirements are all **for new PCs *only***. Given that MS is desperate for as many people as possible to move to Win10 to reduce support scenarios, making UEFI a requirement and removing legacy BIOS/CSM support would be suicide. Not to mention the fact that the Get Windows 10 app allows any suitable BIOS-based system to reserve the RTM download. I would thus recommend that you remove that sentence about UEFI requirement.

Comment: Also, in my experience so far installing in BIOS mode and enabling UEFI later invariably results in an unbootable system. This can be fixed but not without a lot of headache (see answers to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/520762/do-i-need-to-re-install-windows-8-to-enable-uefi) for example). The recommendation in your second paragraph is therefore suspect.